# Swift -'init(cgImage:options:alphaType:)' is deprecated: Replaced by MTIImage(cgImage:options:isOpaque:)

Tags: ios, swift, metal, metalkit

I'm trying to convert a cgImage from the old function to new function but I'm unsure of what the argument for the last parameter should be. Based on the old function's param `alphaType:` argument being `.alphaIsOne` should the new argument for param `isOpaque`: be `true` or `false`?

[image]

```
// old function
let image = MTIImage(cgImage: myCGImage, options: [.SRGB: false], alphaType: .alphaIsOne)

// new function
let image = MTIImage(cgImage: myCGImage, options: [.SRGB: false], isOpaque: false)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "alpha" component of an image (such as one that uses RGBA values) is the "opacity". There are multiple common scales for it (0% - 100%, 0.0 - 1.0, 0 - 255), but in all of them, a lower value indicates *more* transparent.

So in your case, if you had an alpha value of one, then you had a fully opaque image, so you'll want to set `isOpaque` to `true`.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the explanation!